# Как это представить в виде массива структур?

Tags: c++, массивы

Помогите представить в виде массива структур
Нужно вычислить средний балл каждого ученика по итогам года и средний балл всего класса. Распечатать фамилии тех учеников, которые имеют средние баллы от 8 до 12 а средний балл всего класса. От 8 до 10 - хорошист, а от 10 до 12 - отличник. Также нужно указать разницу между средним баллом каждого хорошиста / отличника и средним баллом всего класса. Информацию сохранить в виде массива структур.
Вот то что у меня получилось

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
struct Marks {
char name[80];
int maths;
int hist;
int chem;
} ivanov, petrov, sidorov, kovtun, plaksina;

int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukrainian");
strcpy_s(ivanov.name, "Сергій Іванов");
ivanov.maths = 6;
ivanov.hist = 9;
ivanov.chem = 4;
strcpy_s(petrov.name, "Іван Петров");
petrov.maths = 9;
petrov.hist = 10;
petrov.chem = 9;
strcpy_s(sidorov.name, "Ігор Сідоров");
sidorov.maths = 11;
sidorov.hist = 10;
sidorov.chem = 11;
strcpy_s(kovtun.name, "Марія Ковтун");
kovtun.maths = 8;
kovtun.hist = 5;
kovtun.chem = 7;
strcpy_s(plaksina.name, "Дар'я Плаксіна");
plaksina.maths = 10;
plaksina.hist = 3;
plaksina.chem = 12;

const int n = 1;
double sr_kl = 0, sr_iv = 0, sr_pet = 0, sr_sid = 0, sr_kov = 0, 
sr_pl = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sr_iv = ((ivanov.maths + ivanov.hist + ivanov.chem) / 3);
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sr_pet = ((petrov.maths + petrov.hist + petrov.chem) / 3);
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sr_sid = ((sidorov.maths + sidorov.hist + sidorov.chem) / 3);
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sr_kov = ((kovtun.maths + kovtun.hist + kovtun.chem) / 3);
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sr_pl = ((plaksina.maths + plaksina.hist + plaksina.chem) / 3);
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sr_kl = ((sr_iv + sr_pet + sr_sid + sr_kov + sr_pl) / 5);
    cout << "Середній бал класу= " << sr_kl << endl;
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (sr_iv >= 8 & sr_iv < 10) {
        cout << "Сергій Іванов - " << " Хорошист " << endl << 
"Середній бал учня = " << sr_iv << endl << "Різниця між середнім 
балом учня та середнім балом класу = " << sr_iv - sr_kl << endl;
    }
    else if (sr_iv >= 10) {
        cout << "Сергій Іванов - " << " Відмінник " << endl << 
"Середній бал учня = " << sr_iv << endl << "Різниця між середнім 
балом учня та середнім балом класу = " << sr_iv - sr_kl << endl;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (sr_pet >= 8 & sr_pet < 10) {
        cout << "Іван Петров - " << " Хорошист " << endl << 
"Середній бал учня = " << sr_pet << endl << "Різниця між середнім 
балом учня та середнім балом класу = " << sr_pet - sr_kl << endl;
    }
    else if (sr_pet >= 10) {
        cout << "Іван Петров - " << " Відмінник " << endl << 
"Середній бал учня = " << sr_pet << endl << "Різниця між середнім 
балом учня та середнім балом класу = " << sr_pet - sr_kl << endl;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (sr_sid >= 8 & sr_sid < 10) {
        cout << "Ігор Сідоров - " << " Хорошист " << endl << 
"Середній бал учня = " << sr_sid << endl << "Різниця між середнім 
балом учня та середнім балом класу = " << sr_sid - sr_kl << endl;
    }
    else if (sr_sid >= 10) {
        cout << "Ігор Сідоров - " << " Відмінник " << endl << 
"Середній бал учня = " << sr_sid << endl << "Різниця між середнім 
балом учня та середнім балом класу = " << sr_sid - sr_kl << endl;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (sr_kov >= 8 & sr_kov < 10) {
        cout << "Марія Ковтун - " << " Хорошист " << endl << 
"Середній бал учня = " << sr_kov << endl << "Різниця між середнім 
балом учня та середнім балом класу = " << sr_kov - sr_kl << endl;
    }
    else if (sr_kov >= 10) {
        cout << "Марія Ковтун - " << " Відмінник " << endl << 
"Середній бал учня = " << sr_kov << endl << "Різниця між середнім 
балом учня та середнім балом класу = " << sr_kov - sr_kl << endl;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (sr_pl >= 8 & sr_pl < 10) {
        cout << "Дар'я Плаксіна - " << " Хорошист " << endl << 
"Середній бал учня = " << sr_pl << endl << "Різниця між середнім 
балом учня та середнім балом класу = " << sr_pl - sr_kl << endl;
    }
    else if (sr_pl >= 10) {
        cout << "Дар'я Плаксіна - " << " Відмінник " << "Середній 
бал учня = " << sr_pl << "Sr bal klasa: "<< sr_kl<< "Різниця між 
середнім балом учня та середнім балом класу = " << sr_pl - sr_kl << 
endl;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Кто вам учил такой код писать?  Меняйте своего учителя

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct students
{
  char name[30];
  int maths;
  int hist;
  int chem;
};

/* Прототипи методів */

void getStudents(students *stud, int len);

void display(students *stud, int len);

void goodStudents(students *stud, int len);

void excellentStudents(students *stud, int len);

void averageResults(students *stud, int len);

float averageClassResult(students *stud, int len);

int main()
{
  struct students stud[5];
  getStudents(stud, 5);
  printf("\nІнформація про всіх учнів:\n\n");
  display(stud, 5);
  printf("\nХорошисти: \n\n");
  goodStudents(stud, 5);
  printf("\nВідмінники: \n\n");
  excellentStudents(stud, 5);
  printf("\nСередні бали учнів: \n\n");
  averageResults(stud, 5);
  float r = averageClassResult(stud, 5);
  printf("\nСередній бал класу: %.2f\n", r);
  return 0;
}

/* Введення даних про студентів */
void getStudents(students *stud, int len)
{
  for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
  {
      printf("Учень %d\n",i+1);
      printf("Введіть ім'я : ");
      scanf("%s",stud[i].name);
      printf("Оцінка з математики: ");
      scanf("%d", &stud[i].maths);
      printf("Оцінка з історії: ");
      scanf("%d", &stud[i].hist);
      printf("Оцінка з хімії: ");
      scanf("%d", &stud[i].chem);
  }
}

/* Виведення даних про всіх студентів */
void display(students *stud, int len)
{
  for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
  {
      printf("Учень %d\n",i+1);
      printf("Ім'я учня : %s\n", stud[i].name);
      printf("Оцінка з математики : %d\n", stud[i].maths);
      printf("Оцінка з історії : %d\n", stud[i].hist);
      printf("Оцінка з хімії : %d\n", stud[i].chem);
   }
}

/* Виведення імен хорошистів */
void goodStudents(students *stud, int len)
{
  int condition = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
  {
      if(stud[i].maths>6 && stud[i].hist>6 && stud[i].chem>6) {
        if(stud[i].maths<10 || stud[i].hist<10 || stud[i].chem<10) {
            printf("Ім'я учня : %s\n", stud[i].name);
            condition++;
        }
      }
   }
   if(condition==0) printf("В класі немає хорошистів\n");
}

/* Виведення імен відмінників */
void excellentStudents(students *stud, int len)
{
  int condition = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
  {
      if(stud[i].maths>9 && stud[i].hist>9 && stud[i].chem>9) {
        if(stud[i].maths<=12&& stud[i].hist<=12 && stud[i].chem<=12) {
            printf("Ім'я учня : %s\n", stud[i].name);
            condition++;
        }
      }
   }
   if(condition==0) printf("В класі немає відмінників\n");
}

/* Виведення середніх балів учнів з точністю два знаки після коми */
void averageResults(students *stud, int len) {
   float average, sum, difference;
   float r = averageClassResult(stud, 5);
   for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
   {
     sum = stud[i].maths + stud[i].hist + stud[i].chem;
     average = sum/3;
     difference = r - average;
     printf("%s: Середній бал %.2f, Різниця між середнім балом учня і середнім балом класу %.2f\n", stud[i].name, average, difference);
   }
}

/* Середній бал класу */
float averageClassResult(students *stud, int len) {
   float average, sum=0;
   for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
   sum += stud[i].maths + stud[i].hist + stud[i].chem;
   average = sum/15;
   return average;
}
```